# why does it appear a blank space between to string concatened c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
public string completeHour(string theTime)
    {
        string total="";
        string[] timeArray = theTime.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        string h = timeArray[0];

        string i = timeArray[1];
        string j = timeArray[2];
        MessageBox.Show(h + "+" + i + "+" + j);

        if (h == "  " || i == "  " || j == "  ")
        {
            if (h == "  ")
            {
                h = "00";
                total = (String.Concat("00",theTime)).Trim();
                MessageBox.Show(total);
            }
            else if (i == "  ")
            {
                i = "00";
                total = timeArray[0] + i + timeArray[2];
                //MessageBox.Show("m-=" + total);
            }
            //else if (j == "")
            //{
            //    j = "00";
            //    theTime = timeArray[0] + timeArray[1] + j;
            //    MessageBox.Show("s-=" + theTime);
            //}
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Why `total` is `00 :52:04` (for instance) and not `00:52:04` that was supposed to be?

Comment: Because `theTime` starts with a space.

Comment: Additionally this line: `if (h == "  " || i == "  " || j == "  ")` is actualy useless.

Comment: please use debugger before asking a question.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. What does the first message box shows? Please add some non-space delimiters to the string shown in message box, maybe like this: `MessageBox.Show("\"" + h + "+" + i + "+" + j + "\"")`

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to make sure there are no leading or trailing white characters, you could call

```
string h = timeArray[0].Trim();
```

And then instead of checking the value against `" "`, you could compare it to `String.Empty` or call `h.IsNullOrEmpty()`.
However I'd strongly recommend you to use simpler approach, using a `DateTime` object.

```
DateTime timeObject;
DateTime.TryParse(theTime, out timeObject);
```

and then just work with `Hour`, `Minute` and `Second` properties. This way you get away from custom parsing and make your code more object-oriented, thus easier to read, instead of juggling multiple string objects.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to avoid this is using Trim() when assigning value to total in following two lines:

```
total = (String.Concat("00",theTime.Trim())).Trim();
.
.
.

total = timeArray[0].trim() + i + timeArray[2].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I was using a MaskedTextBox I didn't define a custom mask so, anywhere (I think) the system assumed that 'theTime' was the type of DateTime.
So, the result of String.Concat("00",theTime) was '00  :32:99', for instance.
I´ve solved it by using the variables h, i and j instead of theTime.
Using a DateTime variable was not appropriated because I want to allow the user to insert NULL values for the hours or for the minutes.